# How do you open an html file when pressing on the help button in the title bar (C# windows forms)

Tags: c#, paint

Hi im doing a paint program and im trying to make the help button in the title bar open an html file. I have done this when pressing F1, but I need to do it when pressing the help button in the title bar. Can someone help me?

Windows Forms C# in Visual Studio 2010

Comment: Does anybody know how to make a file run without listing the full directory, because listing the only the file name won't work, only if you list the entire directory.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work.

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    // Min/Max have to be disabled to show "?" button
    MinimizeBox = false;
    MaximizeBox = false;

    HelpButton = true;
    HelpButtonClicked += new CancelEventHandler(Form1_HelpButtonClicked);
}

void Form1_HelpButtonClicked(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    Help.ShowHelp(this, @"my help html\chm file");
}
```

Comment: Thanks :) but somehow I have to list the full directory, which is extremely long in my case. Listing only the file name doesn't work.

I found also some different code that also works, but I don't how to put it in code format like you did